# TouchID (e.g. SecItemCopyMatching) determine which fingerprint was used

Tags: fingerprint, touch-id

Is there any way to determine which fingerprint was used to unlock the key chain data?  E.g. if we have two customers then we might store a separate username/password with each fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Android? Please update your tags with the OS.

For Android and a GMS certified device, I don't think you will be able to access fingerprint-specific info on Android 6.0+.

See: https://source.android.com/compatibility/7.1/android-7.1-cdd.pdf

Section: 7.3.10, 10th bullet

- MUST NOT enable 3rd-party applications to distinguish between individual fingerprints.